# Download a file from a remote server using ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a network drive that I can access using the controller. e.g. "\mydrive\filestorage". I want users to be able to download files that are stored on this server. This means i cannot use a url since these files are outside of the web servers root. It is also not possible for me to setup a web server for this drive, i have no other way to access this data other than reading the file using the controller and downloading it this way.

I have found some tutorials to do it for files that are on the server, but i cant get it to work when using a remote file. I want to have a download link, you click it and the file downloads. Here is the code i have

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string id)
{
    UploadedDocument document = new UploadedDocument(Int32.Parse(id));
    string filecontents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(document.FilePath);
    string filetype = Helpers.GetMimeType(document.FilePath);
    return File(filecontents, filetype);
}
```

I get the following exception

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot...

The filepath variable will be the path of a network drive.

```
\\Netdrive\Uploads\somefile.txt
```

The 2 variables for file contents and file type are being populated correctly. The exception is thrown when the file is returned. When i run the code in debug mode the 2 variables are populated as follows.

```
filecontents = "test\r\n"
filetype = "text\plain"
```

Comment: what is the value of `document.FilePath`?

Comment: Network shares paths always starts with `\\ ` , not with `\ `. Is that a typo?

Comment: there were 2 slashes, the comment tag was removing the first.

Comment: Does your exception come from `ReadAllText` or from `Helpers.GetMimeType`?

Comment: Is `UploadedDocument` a custom class?

Comment: No the exception comes from the return. filecontents = "test\r\n" and filetype = "text/plain". UploadedDocument is a custom class, but i dont believe this is making much of a difference at the moment

Comment: What's the value of `document.FilePath`? Does it use `Server.MapPath` to build the file path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`File(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd492492%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) expects a file name and a mime type, but you are passing the file content as string.

Serve the file directly from your network drive, in this way:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string id)
{
    UploadedDocument document = new UploadedDocument(Int32.Parse(id));
    string filetype = Helpers.GetMimeType(document.FilePath);
    return File(document.FilePath, filetype);
}
```

To force download the file (and bypass the default browser settings file handling, e.g. PDF shown in browser), add a filename as third argument of the File method:

```
return File(document.FilePath, filetype, "myFileName.pdf");
```

Comment: this doesnt download the file. It opens the file in a new browser window

Comment: That's because the file is handled by your browser, and it automatically chooses how to handle it. If you want to *force* the download of the file, then use the overload of `File` method with 3 strings arguments: `return File(document.FilePath, filetype, "myFileName.pdf");`, using the last argument as the file name.

Comment: that did the trick. Since the other answer is being marked as inefficient ill give this the vote as the correct answer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To download file directly,you can do simply

```
return File(path of file, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, name:file will be download using this name);
```

in controller method

as example
to download file:`http://localhost:60494/Content/Audio/123456.mp3`

```
 var audio_path = "/" + path.Substring(path.IndexOf("Content"));
    String audio_name = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return File(audio_path, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, audio_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code for download the file in MVC

```
 public ActionResult Download()
        {
            var filepath = @"\\Netdrive\Uploads\somefile.txt";
            byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = filepath,
                Inline = false,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(filedata, contentType);
        }
```

Comment: Please note that this way you are loading the entire file content into memory, and then, again turning it into a stream. This is a very inefficient way to serve large files, and wastes useless memory.

Comment: Please don't dump "fixed" code, but explain what you changed.